# Python: deep appending to dictionary? - in a single expression

Tags: python

How do I, in a **single expression**, get a dictionary
where one key-value pair has been added to a sub-dictionary 
in some input dictionary? The input dictionary should be left unchanged. It 
can be assumed the sub-dictionary does exist and that the new key-value pair is not already in the sub-dictionary.

**Update 2** (see below for definition of "SOsurvivalConditions", etc.):

The most concise way is:

```
(SOsurvivalConditions['firstCondition'].setdefault('synonym', 'A modern form of RTFM is: Google It.'), SOsurvivalConditions)[-1]
```

**Update 1** :

This meets the given requirements and does not have the
side-effect of modifying the input dictionary:

```
dict((k,dict(v, synonym='A modern form of RTFM is: Google It.') if k == "firstCondition" else v) for k,v in SOsurvivalConditions.iteritems())
```

However the more concise (but statement only) way can
be adapted with a helper function, e.g.:

```
import copy
def dictDeepAdd(inputDict, dictKey, newKey, newValue):
    """
      Adds new key-value pair to a sub-dictionary and
      returns a new version of inputDict.

      dictKey is the key in inputDict for which a new
      key-value pair is added.

      Side-effect: none (does not change inputDict).
    """
    toReturn = copy.deepcopy(inputDict)
    toReturn[dictKey][newKey] = newValue
    return toReturn

dictDeepAdd(
                 SOsurvivalConditions,
                 'firstCondition',
                 'synonym',
                 'A modern form of RTFM is: Google It.'
           )
```

---

The Example:

```
goodStyle = \
{
    'answer': 'RTFM responses are not acceptable on Stack Overflow - Joel Spolsky has repeatedly said so in the Stack Overflow podcasts.',
    'RTFM'  : 'RTFM is, in the less offensive version, an abbreviation for Read The Fine Manual.',
}

SOsurvivalConditions = \
{
    'moodImperative' : 'be happy',
    'firstCondition' : goodStyle,
}
```

'firstCondition' in SOsurvivalConditions now has two key-value pairs.
A new key-value pair, ('synonym', 'A modern form of RTFM is: Google It.'),
needs to be appended and the result should be available in a single expression.

This works (one line, but broken into several here):

```
{
    'moodImperative': SOsurvivalConditions['moodImperative'],
    'firstCondition' :
        dict(
               SOsurvivalConditions['firstCondition'],
               synonym = 'A modern form of RTFM is: Google It.'
            )
}
```

and returns:

```
{'moodImperative': 'be happy', 
 'firstCondition': 
        {'answer': 'RTFM responses are not acceptable on Stack Overflow - Joel Spolsky has repeatedly said so in the Stack Overflow podcasts.', 
         'RTFM': 'RTFM is, in the less offensive version, an abbreviation for Read The Fine Manual.', 
         'synonym': 'A modern form of RTFM is: Google It.'
        }
 }
```

However there is a lot of redundancy in this
expression - all keys are repeated. And 'firstCondition' appears two times. Is there a more
elegant way?

(The names and the content of the datastructures here are made up, but represent a real problem I encountered today. Python version: 2.6.2.).

Comment: I fail to see how the "single-line" constraint can possibly "represent a real problem". The values in SOsurvivalConditions are of heterogeneous types -- one string, one dict -- and all the solutions presented (yours and others) will explode if one attempts to add the new entry to the string; surely it's worth an extra line or two to be robust in the face of such possible errors. And, you never clarify if you want to alter the original structures, or build entirely new ones -- in real problems, this kind of little detail usually _does_ matter!-)

Comment: I want to transform the input (without changing it) and pass the result to a function. So would a helper function instead of a single expression be the preferred solution then?

Comment: I would indeed suggest a helper function, I'm going to edit my answer to suggest one.

Answer (score 5):

```
SOsurvivalConditions['firstCondition']['synonym'] = 'A modern form of RTM is: Google It.'
```

Comment: This will change SOsurvivalConditions. But is it an expression that will return a value? E.g. could I call a function with the above line and expect that the function get passed the (updated) dictionary?

Comment: No, it won't return a value. Is it a requirement that it returns the dictionary in the single line? If so, could you explain the context of what's going on a bit more?

Comment: It is for use in a Django urls.py file where I want to pass (extra) captured information from the URL for use in the template HTML file. Perhaps using helper functions instead of single expressions is the simpler solution.

Comment: @Peter, I agree with the helper function idea, esp. now that you've specified in a comment that you don't want to modify the original data, just to return modified copies -- see my just-edited answer for details of my suggestions given these clarified specs.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one that does meet your peculiar specs (to within the ambiguity with which you've specified them):

```
(SOsurvivalConditions['firstCondition'].setdefault('synonym', 'A modern form of RTM is: Google It.'), SOsurvivalConditions)[-1]
```

This does modify the initial data structures (rather than creating new ones, as @truppo's answer does), and is also an expression returning the overall dictionary (rather than being a statement, like @Evan's answer, or returning None, like @Seth's).

Of course many variants are possible (if you want the new entry to override an existing one with the same key 'synonym', rather than leave any such existing entry alone, you could use `__setitem__` instead of `setdefault`, for example -- it's hard to guess what you want to happen in such corner cases, as your initial specs are so desperately ambiguous and there's no "real use case" context given to help disambiguate them).

**Edit**: with use case now clarified in comments (no changing the original data structures, and an expression is indeed needed, but a helper function would be OK) here's what I would suggest:

```
def addSubEntry(mainDict, outerKey, innerKey, innerValue):
    # copy inner and outer dicts to avoid altering initial data
    result = dict(mainDict)
    inner = dict(result.get(outerKey, {}))
    inner[innerKey] = innerValue
    result[outerKey] = inner
    return result
```

and as the desired expression, use:

```
addSubEntry(SOsurvivalConditions, 'firstCondition', 'synonym', 'A modern form of RTM is: Google It.')
```

Several variants are possible depending on the exact behavior desired in corner cases. This version adds a new dictionary (with just the given inner key-value pair) if there was previously no entry with the given outer-key; if there *was* such a previous entry, it tries to make it into a dict (even if it was, say, a list of key-value tuples), raising an exception if that's just unfeasible.  A stricter version (demanding that the inner entry already existed and was a dict or dict-like object, raising exception instead) might instead use

```
inner = result[outerKey].copy()
```

as the second statement in the body.

Comment: Always glad to help;-). Let me edit my answer to suggest a good "helper function".

Comment: How about changing the method to accept variable number of inner keys to make it more generically applicable? Like `addSubEntry(dic, val, *keys)`

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `dict.update` (documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update))?

```
SOsurvivalConditions['firstCondition'].update({'synonym': 'A modern form of RTFM is: Google It.'})
```

is what, I think, you want.

Comment: It returns None, which is not what he _says_ he wants;-)

Comment: His question utterly lacked clarity. :P

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it's not pretty, and I think you are probably going too far with your lambda/oneliner/whatever you are trying to do :)

```
dict((k,dict(v, synonym='A modern form of RTFM is: Google It.') if k == "firstCondition" else v) for k,v in SOsurvivalConditions.iteritems())
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 is your friend:

```
{**SOsurvivalConditions, 'firstCondition': {**SOsurvivalConditions['firstCondition'], 'synonym': 'A modern form of RTFM is: Google It.'}}
```

A single line expression that returns a dictionary with the additional subitem without modifying the original dictionary nor subdictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this meets your requirements:

```
{k: dict(v, **{'synonym': 'A modern form of RTFM is: Google It.'}) if k == 'firstCondition' else v for k, v in SOsurvivalConditions.iteritems()}
```

This will produce a new dictionary that takes the inner dictionary of the original under `firstCondition` and creates a new dictionary from it with the new item included. One caveat is that if there are other mutable structures in the original dictionary as a value, this will copy over the references to the new dictionary. That didn't seem to be the case in your problem though, and you can easily modify it to also produce copies of those mutable structures.

Here's an affirmation that this works:

```
SOsurvivalConditions = {
    'moodImperative' : 'be happy',
    'firstCondition' : {
        'answer': 'RTFM responses are not acceptable on Stack Overflow - Joel Spolsky has repeatedly said so in the Stack Overflow podcasts.',
        'RTFM'  : 'RTFM is, in the less offensive version, an abbreviation for Read The Fine Manual.',
    },
}
target_dict = {
    'moodImperative': 'be happy',
    'firstCondition': {
        'answer': 'RTFM responses are not acceptable on StackOverflow - Joel Spolsky has repeatedly said so in the Stack Overflow podcasts.',
        'RTFM': 'RTFM is, in the less offensive version, an abbreviation for Read The Fine Manual.',
        'synonym': 'A modern form of RTFM is: Google It.'
    },
}

new_dict = {k: dict(v, **{'synonym': 'A modern form of RTFM is: Google It.'}) if k == 'firstCondition' else v for k, v in SOsurvivalConditions.iteritems()}

assert(SOsurvivalConditions['firstCondition'].get('synonym') is None)  # asserts original dict didn't change
assert(new_dict == target_dict)  # asserts target dictionary is produced
```